# SQL Sum, Return Field that aren't Zero

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've written a query to get the Sum of three fields, except the majority of them sum up to be zero. I need to only return the sums that are greater than zero. Below is the Query

```
SELECT [Product], 
SUM([Pounds]) as SumPounds, 
SUM([Dollars]) as SumDollars, 
SUM([EBITDA]) as SumEBITDA 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE ([Year] = '2017' AND [Date] <= #8/20/2017#) 
SORT BY [Product];
```

Is there a way to only return the sums greater than zero in Access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT [Product], 
       SUM([Pounds]) as SumPounds, 
       SUM([Dollars]) as SumDollars, 
       SUM([EBITDA]) as SumEBITDA 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE ([Year] = '2017' AND [Date] <= #8/20/2017#) 
GROUP BY [Product]
HAVING SUM([Pounds]) + SUM([Dollars]) + SUM([EBITDA]) > 0
```

Comment: Or, `Sum([Pounds] + [Dollars] + [EBITDA]) > 0` as slightly more compact (assuming no NULLs)

Comment: You're a god and I am not. Much obliged!

Comment: Why three SUMs instead of one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use HAVING for filter the result of aggregated  functions

```
SELECT [Product], 
SUM([Pounds]) as SumPounds, 
SUM([Dollars]) as SumDollars, 
SUM([EBITDA]) as SumEBITDA 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE ([Year] = '2017' AND [Date] <= #8/20/2017#) 
HAVING UM([Pounds]) >0  AND SUM([Dollars]) > 0 AND SUM([EBITDA]) >0
SORT BY [Product];
```

if you need  all the 3 value you can use AND as in answer  above  if you need  only one you can use OR